# Given an image how to identify whether it is RAW file or not

Tags: raw, photography-basics, raw-vs-jpeg

I'm a much like beginner level, so pardon me if this is a very basic silly question. Once I've a JPEG photograph image file, how can I find out whether it is a RAW file or not?

Comment: Relevant further reading: [How to convert JPEG to RAW in Photoshop or similar?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/73475/26575)

Comment: To check - are you asking if 'given a jpeg, can we find out if it was once a raw file and then converted' or are you asking 'I believe that RAW is a *type* of jpeg and want to check if this jpeg is RAW'?  (either are reasonable beginner questions, and both are easy to explain, but in different ways)

Comment: I don't think it's a silly question, but I think it's the "wrong" question. Probably what you should be asking is, "[what is a RAW file?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1455)"

Comment: And this one is probably also relevant: [How many different RAW formats are there?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/9646)

Comment: It's been said here at Photo.SE many times before but it bears repeating: There's **no such thing as a raw image.** There is only raw data. Whatever you are viewing on the screen when you open a raw file is a conversion of that data. A light curve must be applied. Demosaicing must be applied to the monochromatic luminance values from each pixel well. Color balance, tint, contrast, etc. are all being applied to the image by the application with which you view it.

Comment: @MichaelClark By that logic there is no such thing as a JPEG or PNG image, which makes the distinction mostly useless.

Comment: JPEGs and PNGs have a *single* correct way to display them. They are already in RGB form and have a color space designated in their metadata. There is only a singular way to correctly display a JPEG or PNG. A raw file is not RGB, it is not gamma corrected, it has no color/white balance, no black points or white points set, etc. There are a near *infinite* number of ways a raw file can be interpreted. If one merely converts the linear luminance values of a raw image file to a raster format, one gets a blob of mostly black nothingness with splotches of dark gray here and there.

Comment: @MichaelC not quite so. JPEG is a lossy format, so each decoder might have slightly different output result depending on the algorithm and settings

Comment: @phuclv each ***encoder*** might create a slightly different JPEG file. But once there is a file, there is one correct way to convert it back to RGB values!

Comment: @Josef emphatic +1

Comment: To be even more pedantic, even so-called raw files can be lossly compressed by the engine (e.g., I recall Nikon's NEF is a lossy format). The raw _file_ is a _representation_ of the actual data as collected by the sensor and then processed by the engine based on input criteria from the processor using one of several algorithms. That is, it really isn't _necessarily_ (and often isn't) a dump of raw sensor data, but rather a (sometimes vendor specific) container for partially processed data and metadata.

Comment: could you add why exactly you want to know that? What would you do if I have a tool to answer your question? That's an important detail

Comment: @Josef not quite, there can be rounding differences between two compliant JPEG decoders. But the differences will be subtle at worst.

Comment: I think perhaps the QUESTION being asked should be ( as a beginner myself this would be my question)...if someone asked me to supply one of my pictures , for editing, “raw”, how do I know which of my pictures actually are? Once upon a time all pictures downloaded off my camera just were. Not so now? When I send pictures via txt or email or messenger...do these go “raw” or have they already, for sending purposes on these platforms, been changed? Or changed straight from the cameras?

Answer (score 67):

> Once I've a JPEG photograph image file, how can I find out whether it is a RAW file or not?

**If you have a JPEG file, then it is not a RAW file.**

RAW isn't a single format, but rather a collective name for image files that contain data straight from the sensor. RAW files need to be processed in order to convert them to more general-purpose image formats like JPEG or PNG. Most cameras can do that processing themselves, so that they save their images in JPEG format, or they can write the RAW data into a file for processing on your computer. Either way, if you know your file is a JPEG file, then by definition it is not a RAW file.

Comment: "RAW isn't a single format, but rather a collective name for image files that contain data straight from the sensor." Well put. In fact, it is a pet peeve of mine that there is a pattern of capitalizing the word "raw" as if it was an initialism. As you say, it is a word that describes general or vendor specific partially processed file type(s) that represents data as it is captured by a sensor and engine combination. Like I said, pet peeve. I'm learning to live with my struggle.

Comment: @jdv See my question [*What, if anything, does “RAW” stand for?*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/30847/4262) for more on that.

Comment: Oh dear. Well, we are going to have to disagree on this. I'll continue to use the word "raw"  for the concept and the initialism or acronym for specific interpretations of raw. You can tell I'm serious because I used the word "initialism".

Comment: @jdv I doubt we really disagree, perhaps just differ in willingness to follow the crowd. *RAW* is definitely a confusing term, but *raw* isn't always clear either. We don't have to solve that here though.

Comment: It's true. I'm mostly joking, which I hope is clear. I think for me, the sticking point is how I get the information across in prose. And when talking about raw formats in general, or even a specific raw format that doesn't overload the term with a .RAW file extension I find it maybe less obscuring to just use the English word without any decoration. It's a deliberate attempt at lessening noise or jargon, especially in the written word.

Comment: @jdv but it *isn't* an initialism or acronym. If it stood for "Robot Armadillo Warriors" and was pronounced "raw", it would be an acronym. If it stood for "Redwood Ambulance Workers" and was pronounced "R-A-W", it would be an initialism. But since it stands for "raw" and is pronounced "raw", it is a plain word, not an acronym or initialism.

Comment: @hobbs, I'm not sure why you seem to be disagreeing with me on this when I've made it clear that I am in agreement with everything you've said. I'm saying it is a peeve of mine that we use the term raw in all-caps _as if_ it was an initialism when it is, as I've already said, decidedly not. _Maybe_, but only maybe, would it make sense when referring to a specific raw file format that uses the ".RAW" extension, but maybe only in that context. If I'm arguing for anything, I'm arguing for clarity in prose. Others may argue for convention. These are both valid approaches.

Comment: And, yes. I recognize I've confused initialism and acronym in some of my earlier comments. I'll reconsider my peeve maybe, since clarity and accuracy in prose is a lost cause and start referring to the format as "R.A.W." This has the advantage of not only being wrong, but annoying the other people who's peeve is no whitespace after the punctuation in abbreviations. (And I may have misused an apostrophe right then, so now I'm throwing my hands up in despair over this whole "written language" thing.)

Comment: We might be getting into [chat] territory here, folks.

Answer (score 23):

Unless somebody frivolously renamed a RAW file, it will never have a file name with the .jpg/.jpeg/.jfif extension. Typical extensions for RAW files will be .raw, .arw (Sony), .dng (Android phones etc.), .nef (Nikon), .cr2 (Canon)...

A JPEG file will always have the text JFIF somewhere near the start if opened in a text or hex editor, among the hieroglyphs (warning: if opening a non-text file in a text editor, NEVER save!). It is not impossible but extremely unlikely for a RAW file to have that.

If you cannot see file name extensions in Microsoft Windows, uncheck "Folder Options"/"Hide extensions for known file types".

Comment: The JFIF criterion doesn't work for the JPG from my three Canon cameras (Ixus 150, 450D, 70D) or my smartphone (Moto G). No JFIF in there, Linux `file` says: `IMG_1385.JPG: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=11, description=                               , manufacturer=Canon, model=Canon IXUS 150, orientation=upper-left, xresolution=200, yresolution=208, resolutionunit=2, datetime=2018:04:17 14:52:46, GPS-Data], baseline, precision 8, 4608x3456, frames 3`. Conversely, you find the JFIF in a RAW file if there is an embedded JPG thumbnail.

Comment: @xenoid: `file` isn't a text/hex editor. Try `xxd` (but you probably don't want to dump the whole file, so I recommend limiting it (e.g. `xxd -l 1024 <file>`)).

Comment: "file" will only be available on a unix or cygwin box usually, or on a mac, not on a standard windows box?

Comment: I tried `grep -i JFIF *.JPG` on whole directories. The only hits are on files I edited (so the image editor does use the JFIF format). I suspect this is because cameras use the [Exif format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) and not the older [JFIF format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format).

Comment: OK, so likely a TIFF header is used... need to examine that....

Comment: @rackandboneman And Canon's CR2 format is also a TIFF derivative. But I find the 'Exif' String in all JPGs and not in any CR2.

Comment: @xenoid is right, [Exif images have the string "Exif" instead of "JFIF" at the beginning of the first chunk.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#Compatibility) Some cameras or programs may create hybrid JFIF/Exif image files that contain both chunks, but those don't really comply with the Exif standard.

Comment: One may try to open the file in some app that doesn't support RAW. E.g., a web browser. Unless a plugin is installed, if it even exists, a renamed RAW file will not be displayed.

Comment: "*If you cannot see file name extensions in Microsoft Windows*" you are wearing a "kick-me!" sign on your back.  Imagine a file called `really_funny.png.exe`, presented by Windows as `really_funny.png`. Far too many people will execute it, and it won't be funny for them.

Answer (score 11):

### Trivial ways to recognize whether a file is a RAW or a JPEG:

1. File ending: JPEGs end with `.jpg` or `.jpeg`, RAWs end with different strings (e.g. `.cr2`, `.nef`, `.arw`, ...)
2. File headers: Usually, formats put some signature in there that tells programs.
3. Size: Given the same size and motive, even quality 100 JPEGs will be significantly smaller. (e.g. 20 MiB vs 5 MiB)
4. Ask a program that knows. Most (if not all) programs use the file header or other file-analyses to determine a file's format. IrfanView even tells you when you have a JPEG with a wrong ending (e.g. `ThisIsNotAPNG.png`)
5. While you can save changes in the image's data to a JPEG by re-encoding it, you cannot e.g. draw a pencil line into a RAW and save it as a RAW - it will need to be a PSD, TIF, JPEG,...

There are more methods, but most involve some experience in this kind of stuff (e.g. a HEX-editor). If you want the answer to be low-level, then I would suggest to move it over to [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

<sup>**Note:** As it would make this answer very long, I have not considered container files. Most RAW files are containers - they include not only the RAW itself, but also a JPEG thumbnail. In my answer, I am only talking about the image file in the respective container - e.g. JPEGs in RAW containers are still JPEGs, and as far as I know, [JPEGs are not container files and therefore cannot contain RAW 'images'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure).</sup>

Comment: At a guess... perhaps more relevant to the OP is that whilst a RAW can be re-processed into a JPG [or PNG etc] you cannot do it the other way, you cannot reprocess a jpg back to a raw.

Comment: @Tetsujin That is true, but it makes a terrible mess of identifying formats :-)

Comment: I'm thinking there's a comprehension issue at root - "Once I've a JPEG photograph image file, how can I find out whether it is a RAW file or not?" ...at that point you don't have a RAW, you have a JPG. A RAW can contain a JPG, but a JPG cannot contain or be transmuted into a RAW.

Comment: I understand relation between JPG and RAW. However, I thought that probably RAW files might be getting saved in .jpg extension. Can that be the case? Actually I was experimenting with a device where it seems to be claiming to support RAW images, however I do not see any option of that, which led me to believe that probably although the image is getting captured in .jpg file it might be actually RAW file by default internally. I was trying to investigate whether my belief was true or not.

Comment: If a file has the ending .jpg, then technically does it not only have 256 luminance value per RGB Channel? Meaning that the RAW file which has 12-14 bit Monochromatic luminance value per pixel has now been de-mosaiced and the values of the RAW data will no longer be available? Making it impossible for a jpeg to contain values higher than 256? I am not overly technical, but interested in knowing how it would be possible for Jpeg to hold values of 16k+.

Comment: There are jpeg variants, both in the original JFIF format and JPEG2000, that can have 12 bits or more per channel. For pure display or print-as-is purposes, and that is what jpeg is meant for, 3 8 bit channels are actually a lot - and usually even an expensive camera won't be 1/2lsb precise even on 8 bit :)

Comment: @Tetsujin since other (better) answers have appeared, I opted to only add it as a fifth way to recognize JPEG vs. RAW - I started with an explanation of RAW vs. JPEG, but it got out of hand :-D

Comment: @AbdulQuraishi as rackandboneman stated, there are JPEG variants that can hold more than 8bit. However, I would use a more modern format for this purpose, as your typical JPEG decoder might not know how to deal with these files, and more modern codecs are often designed for >8bpp. **However, demosaicing is done as a first (visual) step in opening a RAW and cannot be undone later**. You can change the demosaicing algorithm in some software, but still, once it is done, it is done - you cannot re-mosaic the file.

Comment: @TempO'rary Sorry, I missed your comment until now. Added that in the fine-printed **Note:**-setion: While you could mis-name a RAW to `ThisIsMyRAW.JPEG`, it typically will not happen. [JPEG files are not containers - they are segmented files.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure)

Answer (score 2):

RAW format, as generally called, is a group of file types with different suffixes. There are `*.raw` files and proprietary files like `*.cr2` for Canon, for example and many others. I am a Canoneer so the following is based on my experience with my Canon.

Almost every manufacturer has their own RAW file format. Be also careful that some, Canon for sure, updates their RAW format so claim "All [Canon] image tools can open all [Canon] RAW images" is false. To preview a RAW file one need program that can process the the particular file format in particular version. Even mighty Photoshop have issues opening every RAW file.

RAW file is a dump of the data collected from the sensor plus data containing the camera setups. It is complete and lossless acquisition of data from the camera to the memory. RAW format is not an image format at all.

The cameras have built-in image processors (in case of Canon it is named Digic*X*) that interpret the RAW file to JPEG and show on screen and/or store to memory.

When one use any digital camera the internal workflow is:

1. Open the shutter (mechanical: slide first curtain away, digital: start saving the data stream from the chip)
2. Acquire the scene
3. Close the shutter (mechanical: slide second curtain over the chip, digital: stop saving the data stream)
4. Dump the data acquired to the buffer
5. Process the image to jpeg using pre-set options
6. Show preview to the screen.
7. Save the *image*
8. Clear buffer memory.

If the `RAW` mode is selected, the processor saves the data to *image* as-is in the body-specific format. If the `RAW+JPEG` mode is selected, processor saves the data as-is to *image.cr2* (for Canons) and processed image to *image.jpeg*. If `JPEG` mode is selected only the processed *image* is saved and the raw data are lost forever.

That's why the RAW *images* are humongous when compared to true image formats. If you have 12MPx camera with 16bit depth the RAW file holds 12 000 000 * 16 bits of image information plus negligible amount of data keeping the setups.

JPEG is, on the other hand, file format dedicated to store images in files with reasonably size. It is based on lossy compression and benefits from the fact, that 50 shades of black are black to human eye, so why bother? It works similarly to `.mp3` audio format - it ignores the nuances the detector can distinguish but human senses can't. The level of ignorance is regulated by the compression quality.

How to identify RAW files?

- They are humongous
- Few previewers can process them
- The file extension is *not* `jpg` or `jpeg`

Answer (score 1):

Raw image files contain enough data to create a near infinite number of interpretations of that data that will fit in an 8-bit jpeg file.¹ Anytime you open a raw file and look at it on your screen, you are not viewing "THE raw file." You are viewing [one among countless possible interpretations](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/85871/15871) of the data in the raw file. The raw data itself contains a single (monochrome) brightness value measure by each pixel well. With Bayer masked camera sensors (the vast majority of color digital cameras use Bayer filters) each pixel well has a [color filter in front](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/87251/15871) of it that is either red, green, or blue. For a more complete discussion of how we get color information out of the single brightness values measured at each pixel well, please see [RAW files store 3 colors per pixel, or only one?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/86170/15871)

How the image you see on your monitor when you open a raw file will look is determined by how the application you used to open the file chose to interpret the raw data in the file to produce a viewable image. Each application has its own set of default parameters that determine how the raw data is processed. One of the most significant parameters is how the [white balance](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/89956/15871) that is used to convert the raw data is selected. Most applications have many different sets of parameters that can be selected by the user, who is then free to alter individual settings within the set of instructions used to initially interpret the data in the raw file.

If you are viewing an image on a screen, you are **not** looking at a raw file. What you are seeing is one possible *interpretation* of the raw data collected by a camera sensor. That interpretation may be one of several things:

- A jpeg produced by the camera using the raw data from the sensor and the camera's settings current at the time the image was captured.
- A jpeg preview image attached to a raw image file. The jpeg preview is also produced by the camera's internal processor using the camera's settings current at the time the image was captured. It is attached to the raw image file. This preview is normally what one sees when looking at an image on the LCD on the back of the camera when images are recorded as "raw" files. This preview is also what many photo applications will show when you are viewing thumbnails of raw image files on your computer.
- A fresh interpretation of the raw image data by a raw processing application such as Lightroom. Depending on your program settings, when you first open a raw image file, you may see either the jpeg preview image or you may see a new conversion of the raw data based on the current settings of the application with which you opened the image file. If you are seeing a fresh interpretation of the raw image data, it is still in a form that has had the same type of processing applied to it that a jpeg image produced with the same settings would have had.

The thing to keep in mind is that there is no single interpretation of a raw image file that is "THE raw image." Raw data must be processed to be viewed as any meaningful image.  The settings of the various processing steps will determine how the result looks. There is no single inherently "correct" way to process the raw data. Things such as color temperature and white balance, contrast, white point, black point, etc. must be applied to the raw data collected by the sensor before it looks anything like what we call a "photograph."

For more detailed discussions about what the data in a raw image file is and is not, please see these other questions here at Photography at Stack Exchange:

[RAW files store 3 colors per pixel, or only one?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/86170/15871)
[Why can software correct white balance more accurately for RAW files than it can with JPEGs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/100925/15871)
[RAW in ACR vs JPG in ACR](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/85863/15871)
[While shooting in RAW, do you have to post-process it to make the picture look good?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/76351/15871)
[Why do RAW images look worse than JPEGs in editing programs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/41327/15871)
[Why does my Lightroom/Photoshop preview change after loading?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/3668/15871)
[Why is Lightroom changing all the settings on my imported RAWs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/80607/15871)

<sub>¹ Sure, you could take a picture that contains a single pure color within the entire field of view. but most photos contain a wide variation of hues, tints, and brightness levels.</sub>